# Custom trace logs using spring-cloud-sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring-cloud-sleuth:2.0.1.RELEASE with Spring Webflux. The doc talks about logging trace, span, etc using MDC. It also talks about sending traces to Zipkin via HTTP.

I am interested in logging the trace information in more elaborate way. With every log statement, I want to emit the zipkin traces in the JSON format - very close to what's depicted here: https://zipkin.io/pages/data_model.html

What is the best way to accomplish this in sleuth?

Answer (score 0):

You can have s custom span reporter that before sending spans to zipkin will dump the span as a json structure to logs.

UPDATE:

With this PR merged https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/pull/1068, in 2.1.0 you'll have an easy way to implement your own MDC entries

Comment: do you have an example? Not sure if you are referring to brave.SpanCustomizer or something else?

Comment: Ok, I found zipkin2 reporter interface to accomplish what you were suggesting. However that is not what I am looking for. I want to massage the MDC to have extra fields like duration, annotations, endpoint, etc.

Comment: I see so you should implement your own span logger

Comment: you mean by duplicating Slf4jCurrentTraceContext as mentioned here, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/864 ?

Comment: Yes that's what i suggest